# Counting brackets in a string

Tags: javascript, string, counting

been working on a school problem, and haven't been able to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Write a function named countBrackets that accepts a string
and returns the count of square bracket and curly bracket
characters in the string. That is, it should count occurrences of
these four characters “{ } [ ]”. Use function expression syntax.

```
    var countBrackets = function(s){
    let sum = 0

    for(let i = ""; i == s ; i++ )
    if(i ==="{}[]"){
        sum+=i
    }
     return sum}

 console.log(countBrackets("[123],{456},[{}]")) //8
 console.log(countBrackets("Test string")) // 0
```

I'm a little confused on how I'm supposed to get it to count a string I guess.

Comment: When you encounter a specific opening bracket - increase a counter. When you encounter a closing one, decrease it. If in the end the value is not zero, there is a mismatch of brackets.

Comment: Can you explain what you were trying to doe with that for loop? Because the parameters you use don't make sense at all and it's not how you usually make a loop. Can you talk me through your tought process behind this?

Comment: @Thebaklavabandit I've added a new example based on your previous attempt, let me know if it clears things up or if you have questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global regex (regular expression) matching for this. The regex is between `/ /` followed by the g flag to make it global (otherwise it only returns the first result it finds and stops).
Within the regex, `|` is the OR operator, so you match for `/{|}|[|]/`
Since `[` and `]` have special meaning in regular expressions you need to escape those using a `\` so your total regex becomes `/{|}|\[|\]/g`.
This returns an array of matches, I called the function `findBrackets`.
To get the number of brackets, the function `countBrackets` just returns the `.length` of that array.

```js
const findBrackets = str => str.match(/{|}|\[|\]/g);
const countBrackets = str => findBrackets(str) ? findBrackets(str).length : 0;

console.log(findBrackets('qw[e}rt[y]ui{}o{p'));
console.log(countBrackets('qw[e}rt[y]ui{}o{p'));
console.log(countBrackets('no brackets here'));
```

Edit: seeing the code you posted, you decided to use a for-loop to loop over your string, which is a totally valid solution.
Note that in my above example 
`const findBrackets = str => str.match(/{|}|\[|\]/g);`
Is basically the same but a newer way of writing functions (with a few nuances)
I could have written:

```
var findBrackets = function(str) {
   return str.match(/{|}|\[|\]/g);
}
```

instead which would be almost the same.

If you want to loop over a string, you can access a letter in the string by using square bracket notation, so for example

```
const testString = 'hello';
console.log(testString[1]);
```

Would output the letter 'e'.

So to use this in a function:

```js
const countBrackets = (str) => {
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === '[' || str[i] === ']' || str[i] === '{' || str[i] === '}') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

console.log(countBrackets('qw[e}rt[y]ui{}o{p'));
```

Here you loop over the string from 0 to < length of the string and check every letter of it, by seeing if str[i] is {, }, [ or ], and if it is you increment a counter. After that's done you return the final count.

Comment: The first snippet fails if there are no brackets in the string, and the regex will look better with a character class rather than alteration. The second one would be simpler with a `for..of` loop and `includes` instead of `||`'s.

Comment: @georg thanks for the input, I've edited the first snippet. I agree with you on the second one, and it looks terrible, but I tried to fit this to the level of the question. It's debatable what is easier to understand though, but since OP has trouble with a normal for loop already, an explicit if with `||` seemed more fit.

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much, you really went above and beyond the call of duty here. Really helped out with how I understand this!

Comment: @Thebaklavabandit no problem :) Could you mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem?